# Getting a Process ID & Assigned to a variable and kill the process in Bash Script

Tags: bash, pid, kill

I store in a variable an executed command like so:

`pio device monitor -p COM22 -b 115200 --no-reconnect | grep -E -o -m 1 '[A-Za-z0-9]{12}'`

`pio device monitor` is a command to watch custom logs from an esp32, I use these logs to extract the wanter value (something like C8F09E0AA13C).

I want to run this command in the background and when the command return something, kill the process.

The script works as expected. The command stored in IDFound run in the background and as soon it found something the loop stop and the process is killed and I get the wanted value.

```
# /bin/bash

regex='[A-Za-z0-9]{12}'
port=COM22
unset -v IDFound

if ! [[ $IDFound =~ $regex ]] ; then

    echo 'Please press the reset button of the ESP-prog'

    IDFound=$(pio device monitor -p $port -b 115200 --no-reconnect | grep -E -o -m 1 $regex &)

    # Get PID of this command
    pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/pio/{print $2}')

    # kill the process with PID
    kill $pid

fi

echo $IDFound
```

But my problem is that I get PID with the `pio` keyword and I run another similar command in my script. I don't want to kill the wrong process.

I want to get the PID with `$!` to avoid mistake. How could I achieve that ?

Comment: `$!` is available to that bash script which actually starts the process in the background (and you don't show where this happens). You could there write this PID to a file and process this file from your kill script, but you have to be careful to avoid a race condition. Perhaps it's better to use your `pio` tool and just analyze its output in a way to avoid mistake. You did not show the output of _pio_, so I can't recommend anything concrete.

Comment: Also, you basically do a `IDFound=$( .... &)` , and it doesn't make sense to grab the standard ouput from a process which you had put into background. What exactly are you doing here? Perhaps you need to tell us more about the behaviour of `pio`.

Comment: The `Pio` tools only display logs from an esp32. From these logs, I grep something like `C8F09E0AA13C`. My problem is that I want to store this value and in the same time get the PID to kill it after.

Comment: `pio device monitor` never stops until i kill the process. So that why I have to run this process in the background waiting for my wanted value. And as soon as get the value, I want to stop the process.

Comment: What do you mean by _in the **same time** get the PID_. Is the PID also stored in the logs? Still, running the `grep` in background is nonsense.

Comment: Your variable `IDFound` will be set, once the process inside the parenthesis is finished. It doesn't matter whether this process is in foreground or in background. Therefore the `&` does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry I will try to be more clear. The `pio` command never stops until you kill the process or `^C`.  If I dont use `&` I get the wanted value but after `^C`. My purpose is simple to run this pio command, wait for the result to come and stop it.

Comment: In this case, start the `pio` in the background and redirect its output to a file. In `$!` you have the pit. Then write a separate program which continually reads the file (similar to what `tail -f` is doing and stops when it has the information you are looking for). It then somehow (via stdout or another file) passes this information back to the caller. Basically you separate the task into three pieces: (1) Running pio in the background + saving the output, (2) checking the condition for killing pio, and (3) a master script controlling these two parts.